# Learning about tensor products in linear algebra courses

Tags: linear-algebra, tensor-products

**Question**: What references are accessible to a student who has taken Linear Algebra (at the level of Axler's *Linear Algebra Done Right*) and wants to learn tensor products?

My aim is to get a good enough understanding of tensor products to learn from Humphreys *Lie Algebras and Representation Theory*.

For some reason, it seems most courses in Linear Algebra at undergrad level never touch tensor products at all so, I never got to learn it.

Comment: Try [Suetin-Kostrikin-Manin, Linear Algebra and Geometry](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Linear_Algebra_and_Geometry/eUFZDwAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=0), an undergraduate text that has a chapter on tensor products and algebras, and recent [Erdman, Elements of Linear and Multilinear Algebra](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Elements_Of_Linear_And_Multilinear_Algeb/xvMTEAAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=0) that uses invariant approach with differential forms and applications to manifolds.

Comment: Possibly [**A Second Course in Linear Algebra**](https://www.amazon.com/dp/0471626023) by William C. Brown (1988) is worth looking over, as besides tensor products, it may have much else of later use to you. Incidentally, I'm surprised there are no reviews at amazon.com, as I've found this book quite useful over the years (I've had my copy of the book since 1989 or 1990) when I want to read-up (or refresh myself) on something that is a bit beyond the standard Halmos and Hoffman/Kunze level linear algebra texts.

Comment: Possibly Werner Greub's "Multilinear Algebra"?